# Access Master Page public method from user control/class/page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls, master-pages

I am to access a method on my master page. I have an error label which I want to update based on error messages I get from my site.

```
public string ErrorText
{
    get { return this.infoLabel.Text; }
    set { this.infoLabel.Text = value; }
}
```

How can I access this from my user control or classes that I set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page should contain next markup:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.master" %>
```

then `Page.Master` will have not a type of `MasterPage` but your master page's type, i.e.:

```
public partial class MySiteMaster : MasterPage
{
    public string ErrorText { get; set; }
}
```

Page code-behind:

```
this.Master.ErrorText = ...;
```

---

Another way:

```
public interface IMyMasterPage
{
    string ErrorText { get; set; }
}
```

(put it to App_Code or better - into class library)

```
public partial class MySiteMaster : MasterPage, IMyMasterPage { }
```

Usage:

```
((IMyMasterPage )this.Page.Master).ErrorText = ...;
```

Comment: Hey there abatischev, I'm having exact same issue as OP. I'm about to try the interface route, that looks swift :)  Just curious, is MasterType, used in the first example valid in a User control?  I know this works fine with child pages, wondering if there's a way to get this to work with user controls before implementing option 2.  Thanks!

Comment: @Chris: Hi! As far as I know - unfortunately no, it doesn't work for UserControls. UC knows nothing about parent page's master page, just has a reference to them: this.Page, this.Page.Master, so option #2 is the only one I know

Answer (score 5):

To access the masterpage:

```
this.Page.Master
```

then you might need to cast to the actual type of the master page so that you could get the `ErrorText` property or make your master page implement an interface containing this property.

Comment: How can I use this.Page.Master from a class. It does not seem to work for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416691/how-to-reference-a-master-page-from-a-user-control